# Unable to edit question without also editing the question title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, title

When I attempt to edit the body of [this question of another user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75058134/12149471) in order to fix the formatting, I get the following error message:

> Title cannot contain "troubleshoot in implement tokens in my C".
>
> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

In my opinion, this error message would only make sense if I were changing the title, but I am only editing the body of the question.

Therefore, I am reporting this as a bug.

Comment: The title is pretty bad, though. If you're taking the time to edit the post anyway, why not change it to something actually useful?

Comment: This is not a bug, it's intentional, and there is a dupe for this

Comment: The example question is locked now (*"This post was returned to Super User"* - the OP is likely question-banned on Stack Overflow, thus likely the attempt at Super User). Do you have another example?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: No, I'm afraid I do not have another example. This was the first time I encountered this problem. My guess is that the poster of the question was never told to change the title, because it originated on the "Super User" site and not on Stack Overflow. Then, after the question migrated to Stack Overflow, all further edit attempts were rejected, until the title got fixed.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel that would be correct. The quality filter is on SO, not on the original site it was from. You can also encounter a similar situation if you're editing an old post from before the quality filter was implemented. In that case, the question would be originally from SO just with a terrible title from before the system tried to prevent those. Same result, though, you should edit the title to be not terrible. Or alternatively, just don't edit. I often cancel an edit if I can't really justify spending the extra time to edit the title of the question.

Comment: There's an entire forest of duplicates here, but AFAICT absolutely nothing actually addresses the root of the question: **Why were the now-rejected titles accepted before**? **Why aren't we allowed** to edit the body without also editing the now-deemed-unacceptable title? **What if we can't think of anything better right now**? **Why doesn't the system look** for existing questions that don't meet current standards, even when it doesn't require human intervention? Therefore, I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 9):

I'm reviving this old question to complain, because I ran into this issue a few times during my most recent major cleanup effort.

The problem occurs because the question title doesn't satisfy current filters, but the relevant filters weren't in place when the question was posted (pedantically, when the title was most recently edited). These filters universally report an error that the "title cannot contain 'xyz'", where xyz is the *entire proposed title*. This does nothing to explain the rule that tripped the filter. It's uninformative (it has no more information content than "this title is not acceptable") and even a put-down (because of the "contain" phrasing, it comes across as if the system somehow predicted your title and has a specific rule to prevent exactly that title).

For whatever reason (probably because mass-deleting all the questions overnight wouldn't have been acceptable, and it isn't clear what *else* to do), when these filters are/were introduced, they don't get applied retroactively.

As a consequence, the site drowns in questions that the site deems unacceptable.

This situation should itself be considered unacceptable, and **<kbd>status-bydesign</kbd> is not an acceptable resolution** here.

This state of affairs means that new users who want to learn the site standards by example, are exposed to tons of bad examples. It also causes a massive headache for curators. When I find a low-quality duplicate with answers, I often find that my hands are tied:

- I can't edit to improve the question, because the existing title won't go through.
- I can't just change the title, because all the *good* titles are taken already (as one should expect for a frequent duplicate!). To make it go through, I'd have to junk it up deliberately, in a way that avoids the filters, which is to say, deliberately set a bad example. Plus, even if I wanted to do this, it's mentally taxing because of the artificial restrictions.
- It wouldn't roomba even if I decide to close it as "needs details or clarity" instead (which would be a lie anyway, since I understood it well enough to identify the obvious duplicate; and would be obviating my duty to fix clarity problems that I'm perfectly capable of fixing myself *if the system would just let me*; and needs help from two others), because it has answers.
- Manual deletion is burdensome; I have to wait unless it's at -3, and then I also have to get two other people to pay attention to the same piece of old garbage while also not falling afoul of whatever voting-ring policies.

If the system thinks that a certain regex on a question title is *such* a red flag that it should prevent a new question from going through, **what about existing questions** that trip the same flag?

Comment: There could be a [grandfathering](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grandfather#Verb_2) (*grandmother* is not a verb) rule: The filters are not applied if a post is more than XX days old. They are intended for the initial revision anyway.