# Can the system consider questions spam and prevent the OP from editing them?

Tags: support, specific-question

I recently encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065181/javafx-application-dont-work-for-mac-when-i-am-adding-to-maven-two-dependencies) where an OP created a new account to [re-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76058255/javafx-application-works-on-linux-and-windows-but-not-on-macs-our-macs-have-m-c) a question. When someone pointed out in the comments that they should just edit the original question, the OP claimed the following:

> I wasn´t able to edit the question, and because of this i used this account, I tried to edit the question, so that I can write, that when I am deleting the two dependencies, that its work, but when I try to edit the question, stack overflow says that the question is a spam, and dont change the question.

I was able to edit the question just fine when I tried. However, I'm slightly confused by the OP's claim; is it possible that what they're claiming is actually true? If so, why would the system consider the other question spam? It's admittedly not a great question, but I don't see any obvious reason to suspect spam (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: I can see how they might trip up one of the quality regex-s (ie *It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.*) but there is no sign this is spam now or has been in other revisions.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I'm confused too - I don't see any obvious reason to consider this spam.

Comment: It would be nice if we got the *actual* error from the OP; even some seasoned users "confuse" words for others (such as "closed" for "removed" or "deleted"). I wonder if they say "spam" but mean something else.

Comment: Without more information from the person with the problem, it's not possible to know what the actual issue was. Given typical actions, the problem was most likely PEBKAC, although the specific statement from the OP that the system stated it was *spam* is unusual.

Comment: I think there's a filter that will block a post because it "looks like spam"; perhaps it also blocks edits that meet the same criteria?  In this case, it would be the contents that they were trying to submit as an edit, rather than the original version of the question.

Comment: Judging by their poor writing style is is quite likely that they used the word spam incorrectly, and the actual reason was something else entirely.

Comment: @RyanM Yes but there is a problem with that. Example with [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422593/10952503) some others that I don't find, where the spam filter didn't detect OP but is angry when editing. It can be because of something like that

Comment: It is kind of unfortunate that Stack Overflow uses terminology which overlaps with internet lingo. Spam is one of those abused words just like "meme". This amount of uncertainty is avoidable. It'd be great if Stack Overflow would name it for what it is in the context of SO - advertising.